# Possible bug? R markdown cannot include ggplot figures

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I ran into a problem about markdown. In an ordinary R script, I click the Compile Report button (ctrl+shitf+k), and the result did not include any graphs. It took me some time before I figured out the fix is to delete the graphics.off() command in the heading. However, I have graph commands like ggplot or plot after the graphics.off() command. So why are all graphs deserted?

Moreover, I am a Chinese user, and my computer is just the default coding in Win10 Simplified Chinese, not in UTF-8 coding. So sometimes I have errors like "Error in abs_path(input) :
The file 'D:/??/assignment 1/HW1.R' does not exist.", where the ?? are Chinese characters. I wonder if there is a way to fix this, while keeping my overall setting unchanged? I don't want to use the UTF-8 coding for my entire system, because I have some old txt files stored in other formats.

Attached is the code that caused some trouble, and I used to add the command in the headings for housekeeping. More interestingly, last week this code works well with knitting, but this week I have to delete the graphics.off() command to have graphs in the knitted HTML file.

```
graphics.off() # Shuts down all open graphics
rm(list = ls())  # Remove objects from the workspace
# Set the working directory
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
##########
#Problem 1
##########
#question a
library(XLConnect)#a very helpful package for excel sheets
my_book = loadWorkbook("./HW1data/data_assignment1.xlsx")
df = readWorksheet(my_book, sheet = "stock_monthly")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#transforming data into "clean" format
df = gather( df, key = "company", value = "ret", -DATE ) 
df[,1] = as.Date(as.character(df[,1]), format = "%Y%m%d")  
  
  
#question b
df = df %>% mutate(Lret =log(1 + ret)) #store the log result as Lret

#question c
library(ggplot2)
#for simple return
fig1 = ggplot(df, aes(x = DATE, y = ret))+
  geom_point(size = 0.5)+ facet_grid(rows = vars(company))
print(fig1)
```

And the wrong output looks like this:

[image: The file ended without any figures, but the code executed correctly]

Comment: Why do you have `graphics.off()`?

Comment: I've never seen anyone use `graphics.off()` before. Is there a reason you can't delete it if it solves your problem?

Comment: It also seems pointless to put `rm(list = ls())` in an Rmd file - files are generally knit in their own sessions.

Comment: I thought graphics.off() and rm(list = ls()) may be a good idea, because I have them at the beginning of every problem section, so it just clear out old graphs and data from the previous question and free up storage spaces. Like you have a clear command before some matlab scripts.